# Android - Attempt to invoke virtual method on a null object reference

Tags: android

I'm working on a projecto right now (it's my firs time working with android studio).

The code send's a string to a microcontroller to read some data, if i call the method from the onclick of a button everthing work's perfect, but if i call it at the end of another process the app crash with this error.

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.emether, PID: 8490
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.emether.MainActivity$ConnectedThread.write(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
    at com.emether.MainActivity$3.onClick(MainActivity.java:149)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:8160)
    at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:16221)
    at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:1194)
    at com.emether.MainActivity$1.handleMessage(MainActivity.java:114)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:246)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8512)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:602)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1130)
```

Button code

```
 buttonToggle.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String cmdText = null;
            cmdText ="<Read>";
            connectedThread.write(cmdText);
        }
    });
```

This is where i get the error.

```
handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()) {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            switch (msg.what) {
                case CONNECTING_STATUS:
                    switch (msg.arg1) {
                        case 1:
                            toolbar.setSubtitle("Connected to " + deviceName);
                            buttonConnect.setEnabled(true);
                            buttonToggle.setEnabled(true);
                            buttonToggle.performClick()---- **Error line**;
                            break;
                        case -1:
                            toolbar.setSubtitle("Device fails to connect");
                            buttonConnect.setEnabled(true);
                            break;
                    }
                    break;
```

Thanks in advance.

I tried to debug the app but if i add a breakout to the process "cmdText" it's not null and code works perfect.... It's like something need some delay (?) to not be null.